# US Preclearance at Dublin airport before transit in Canada

Tags: connecting-flights, pre-clearance, dub, yul

My husband and I (US citizens) will be flying Dublin - YUL - Chicago ORD next month.  Can we use the preclearance in Dublin for customs?  The last time we went through Montreal the customs area was so backed up and slow, we missed our flight into Chicago.  We do NOT want that to happen again this time.

Comment: This seems really unlikely to me. How are the people at YUL supposed to route just one passenger straight to the post-US-preclearance area? Even if you have a stamp in your passport, you've been hanging out with all kinds of not-precleared people who are (for example) just flying from Dublin to Montreal, or carrying on to somewhere else in Canada. Since you've mixed with non-cleared people, you're not really cleared any more. But perhaps someone who's made the trip can give a more definitive answer.

Comment: Related:  https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/114406/4171  "How does US preclearance work in Dublin?"

Answer (score 8):

As far as I can tell, from experience at DUB and their website, this service is only available for flights going from DUB to US airports. You will have to clear US customs at YUL unfortunately.

[Link to FAQs for US Preclearance at DUB](https://www.dublinairport.com/flight-information/travelling-to-usa/faqs)

> If you are travelling from Dublin to the US on your connecting flight you can use the Preclearance facility in Dublin and will not have to go through US customs when you land.
>
> If you fly from Dublin to another airport outside of the US before travelling on to the US and if that airport that does not offer Preclearance you will have to go through customs in the US.